# Cross-site publishing item page breaking if friendly url has hyphen

Tags: 2013, managed-navigation, cross-site-publishing, url-rewriting

Using cross-site publishing with managed navigation and friendly urls. I had a term with a space in it, **Dark tan**, which SP automatically changed to a url location of **dark-tan**.

For the category pages located at //colors/dark-tan, the CSWP worked just fine and retrieved all items with that tag. But when I clicked one of those items to go to the item details page //colors/dark-tan/378 nothing was displayed.

If I changed the friendly url to something like //colors/darktan/378, then it worked as expected.

I found I could use space character (got changed to %20 in the browser) and other characters like +. Any idea why an item page can't accept a dash in the url?

Comment: Also breaks with underscore! Crazy.

Comment: Just ran into this again. One site they work another site they don't. Anybody?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Please let me know whether anyone knows how to fix

Comment: Finally fixed it. On Search schema we have to ensure On FriendlyURL, "Complete Matching" is enabled

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? Did you do this at the site collection or site level? And if it is on you get hyphen and not checked you get %20? Or the other way around? Did you have to re-index or anything else?